# How to improve a simple Keras model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm starting to play with Keras and those kinds of models but I don't think I get all this yet. I fiddled with a lot of stuff but only managed to make the situation worse. My objective is to reach an accuracy higher than 91% (91% accuracy is the output of this model).
here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
input_size = 10
output_size = 2

hidden_layer_size = 500


model = tf.keras.Sequential([

tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'), 
tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'), 


tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax') # output layer
])






 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])




 batch_size = 50


 max_epochs = 100



 early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5)



 model.fit(train_inputs, 
      train_targets, 
      batch_size=batch_size, 
      epochs=max_epochs,
      
      
      callbacks=[early_stopping],
      validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets), 
      verbose = 2 
      )
```

I don't know if I formatted this right here, I just made this account and I am a total beginner in this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way anyone can help you achieve a better accuracy as its completely dependent on the data and the problem you are trying to model. Just showing the code is not enough.

I would recommend using a `model.summary()` to see the layers and number of trainable parameters in the model for your reference first. And I would recommend spending some time on the Keras documentation as well.

```
https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks
```

Two things can happen when you are building a NN architecture for training specific data -

1. It can underfit - Meaning the model isn't complex enough to learn the patterns in the data. Increase the number of trainable parameters by increasing of layers, and size of each layer in that case.
2. It can overfit - This is a better scenario. This means the model is so complex that it has overfitted on the training data and not generalizable on the testing data. You can reduce the number of training parameters in such a case and/or use dropout layer between the dense layers.